# How does Promise.resolve() work under the hood? Specifically, how exactly does it unwrap thenables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

According to MDN:

> ...if the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state;

This piqued my interest a bit, so I wanted to see if it was possible to re-implement this functionality in pure Javascript.  What I ended up with is this:

```js
function resolve(p){
    if (
        p !== null &&
        (
            typeof p === "object" ||
            typeof p === "function"
        ) &&
        typeof p.then === "function"
    ) {
        return p.then(
            function resolved(value){
                return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
                    resolve(value);
                });
            },
            function rejected(error){
                return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
                    reject(error);
                });
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(p);
        });
    }
}
```

So I tested this with a variety of values:

```js
var a = new Promise (resolve => resolve("hello"));
var b = "hello";
var c = {
  then: onFulfilled => onFulfilled("hello")
};
var d = {
  then: onFulfilled => {
    onFulfilled("hello")
  }
}

Promise.resolve(a); //Promise {<resolved>: "hello"}
Promise.resolve(b); //Promise {<resolved>: "hello"}
Promise.resolve(c); //Promise {<resolved>: "hello"}
Promise.resolve(d); //Promise {<resolved>: "hello"}

resolve(a); //Promise {<resolved>: "hello"}
resolve(b); //Promise {<resolved>: "hello"}
resolve(c); //Promise {<resolved>: "hello"}
resolve(d); //undefined -- uh oh.
```

So obviously since `d`'s `then` method doesn't return anything, the result is undefined... but if I am looking at this right, Promise.resolve() is extracting this value under the hood somehow?  Is it automagically pulling out the return value of the `onFulfilled` function call?  Or am I looking at this completely wrong?

Comment: `then` resolves to the value returned by the callback. It did not return any in your `d`

Comment: Aye, but Promise.resolve() actually does cast d to a promise with a resolved "hello".  Somehow it found the value despite d's then method never returning.  I was just curious if my train of thought here is accurate.  If the JS engine is doing something here outside the capabilities of the script, that's understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.resolve` does not rely on the return value of the `.then()` invocation on the thenable value. It rather looks similar to this:

```
function resolve(v) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (Object(v) === v && typeof v.then === "function") {
            v.then(resolve, reject);
        } else {
            resolve(v); // fulfill (no recursive resolution)
        }
    });
}
```

This is usually known as the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), but it's warranted when we cannot trust the `then` method. I recommend to take a look at how [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) specifies dealing with thenables.

Comment: This is... a lot simpler than I was thinking.  I had it inside out. And thanks for the link!